# Is it possible to embed only shiny app output in markdown document?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I want to write my shiny Output into word document.

I come up with idea of interacting `shiny app` with `r markdown`.
But I only see that one can embed the whole app (Input and output) in `r-markdown`.

I would appreciate it if someone can show me how to embed only Output. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I have been only searching whether it is possible to do so but haven't found the solution.

Comment: Outputs have ids associated with it, you can scrape that maybe?